# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt[4]{z^2+2}}$

Tags: calculus

I have calculate the inverse as 
$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt[4]{2} \sqrt{\pi } x^{3/2}}+\frac{945 \Gamma \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}{256 \sqrt[4]{2} \sqrt{\pi } x^{11/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-\frac{15 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{16 \sqrt[4]{2} \sqrt{\pi } x^{7/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-\frac{x^5 \Gamma \left(\frac{13}{4}\right)}{90 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}+\frac{x^3 \Gamma \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-\frac{2 x \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
could you check with numerically inverse laplace calculator 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica 11.0 code:

```
F[z_] := Sqrt[z]/(z^2 + 2)^(1/4)
melsol = 1/Gamma[p] MellinTransform[F[z], z, p, GenerateConditions -> False] /. p -> (1 - p);
sol = melsol // TrigToExp // FunctionExpand;
sol2 = InverseMellinTransform[sol, p, x] // FullSimplify
```

We need to add Dirac delta function to `sol2` it was everything correct.

> $-\frac{1}{2} x \, _1F_2\left(\frac{5}{4};\frac{3}{2},2;-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+\delta (x)$

Where $_1F_2$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.

Numeric check:

```
sol3 = LaplaceTransform[sol2+DiracDelta[x], x, s] // FullSimplify
(*1/(2 + s^2)^(9/4) (-8 (1 + 2/s^2)^(3/4) (2 + s^2)^(1/4) + Sqrt[s] (6 + 5 s^2 + s^4 - (1 + 2/s^2)^(3/4) s^(3/2) (2 + s^2)^(1/4)) + 
4 (2 + s^2)^(1/4) (5 Hypergeometric2F1[-(3/4), 1/2, 3/2, -(2/s^2)] - 3 Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1/2, 3/2, -(2/s^2)]))*)
sol3 /. s -> 2 // N
(*0.903602*)
F[2] // N
(*0.903602*)
```

for x=1.

```
N[-(1/2) x HypergeometricPFQ[{5/4}, {3/2, 2}, -(x^2/2)] + DiracDelta[x] /. x -> 1, 20]
(*-0.40335058864991806300*)


1/(2*2^(1/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*x^(3/2)) + 
945*Gamma[9/4]/(256*2^(1/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*x^(11/2)*Gamma[1/4]) - 
15*Gamma[5/4]/(16*2^(1/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*x^(7/2)*Gamma[1/4]) - 
x^5*Gamma[13/4]/(90*Gamma[1/2]) + x^3*Gamma[9/4]/(3*Gamma[1/4]) - 
2*x*Gamma[5/4]/Gamma[1/4] /. x -> 1 // N

(* 0.261485*)
```

Yours solution is wrong.

Comment: Hi Mariusz your method not always works cause the not all function has as denominator Gamma(k+1) in the denominator as taylor seriescoefficient .

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it works.:)

Comment: but sol3 maple gives $$-\frac{12 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{2}{s^2}\right)-20 \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{2}{s^2}\right)+s^4+\left(\left(\frac{2}{s^2}+1\right)^{3/4}+4\right) s^2-3 \sqrt{s} \left(s^2+2\right)^{3/4}+8 \left(\frac{2}{s^2}+1\right)^{3/4}-\left(s^2+2\right)^{3/4} s^{5/2}+4}{\left(s^2+2\right)^2}$$ at s=2 gives -0.096398 not 0.903602

Comment: @antonioasis. I do not understand what do  you mean  "but sol3 maple gives"?

Comment: ok.I forgot to add DiracDelta[x]+sol2.I'm update the answer.

Comment: @antonioasis. I'm using Maple 2016.1 and he found nothing, how it possible?I mean laplace(sol2+Dirac(x),x,s)?

Comment: the method it is fine i used the same but not always works thanks anyway